# How to create a jpa query that takes multiple (dynamic) number of ranges for between clause to fetch results

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am writing a JPA native query for searching records.
I have a table lets say "machines" which contain a numeric column "capacity" which stores capacity of machine, search input can contain List of ranges of capacity in which the machines should be filtered.

For example range list can contain

- 10 to 20
- 25 to 30
- 32 to 40

So the machines having capacity between any of above ranges should be fetched.

Here is my native query which works for only one element from capacity ranges 
How to make it dynamic so that it would support for multiple such capacityMin and capacityMax values.

Thanks in advance.

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM machine m where m.status='A' " + 
            "and (:capacityMin IS NULL or (m.capacity>= :capacityMin and m.capacity<= :capacityMax))" , nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Object[]> searchMachines(@Param("capacityMin") Integer capacityMin,@Param("capacityMax") Integer capacityMax);
```

Comment: I think the only way you could do this in a single query would be to use either the Criteria API or QueryDSL to build a dynamic 'or' clause. Otherwise, you would need to call your query once for each range.

Comment: Thanks Alan.. I wanted it in single query itself because it also have to return results with pagination. So maintaining start offset, limit and count in case of multiple queries would be so complicated.

Comment: I would suggest then looking at QueryDSL. Spring data supports it out of the box. It gives you very powerful querying capabilities for zero code. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl

Comment: Thanks for the reference I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a few parameters then use the solution you already found the solution for the first parameter

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM machine m where m.status='A' " + 
            "and (:capacityMin IS NULL or (m.capacity>= :capacityMin ) " +
            "and (:capacityMax IS NULL or (m.capacity<= :capacityMax )" , nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Object[]> searchMachines(@Param("capacityMin") Integer capacityMin,@Param("capacityMax") Integer capacityMax);
```

When you have many optional parameters you can better use the already mentioned Criteria API or QueryDSL

Comment: Your answer is perfect for single range of min & max. In my case, its multiple ranges of such min max combinations. and it is not defined that how many such combinations will I receive from requesting client .

Comment: The @Query annotation works fine with a fixed query and a fixed number of parameters. In your case the number of parameters is dynamic. You should use the Criteria API of QueryDSL as Alan Hay already mentioned.